# Install Java using command prompt and set up JAVA_HOME path

Tags: java, batch-file, command

I need to set up Java 8 in Windows using a Batch file, and set the Java path as the environment variable JAVA_HOME.

What should I write in my batch file?

Comment: Java 8u20 (the latest version) already adds a path in the environment variable - is that not enough?

Comment: yes you are right but if I want to install that in a specific folder means a target folder than what will be code of line ?

Comment: @AnupamSharma You can choose the installation directory directly from the installer. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want that it does not prompt for installation directory and just setup directory that I mentioned in batch file code

Comment: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/silent_install.xml

Comment: thanks let me try this one

Comment: @BackSlash: Thanks its much helpful and solved my problem :)

Comment: @Backslash : can you please suggest me a batch file command to unzip a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the JAVA_HOME environment variable using

`setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.x.x.x\bin"`

setx is similar to UNIX's setenv utility